# How to delete element onclick in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have made CARD's which display's `username`. When I click on the delete button i.e cross or cancel button it should remove the CARD's from the `tasklist` here tasklist is state variable. I am using `.map()` method to iterate over each task and display it. I want to delete the task card of a particular user when I click on the red cross button (see screenshot) currently only the window appears saying -> `are you sure you want to delete it` if I click yes it should delete it.

Code:

```
import React, {Component} from "react"; 

export default class Tasks extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            taskList:[],
            taskName:"",
            type:"classification",
            datasetName:"",
            allDatasets:[],
            users:[],
            names:[]
        }
    }

triggerDelete(task){
        if(window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this task?")){

        }
    }

render(){
        return(
            <div className="tasks-wrap">
                <h1 onClick={()=>{
                   this.props.history.push("/taskdetails");
                }}>Your Tasks</h1>
                {
                            this.state.taskList.map((task,index)=>{
                                return(
                                    <div key={index} className="item-card" onClick={()=>{
                                        window.sessionStorage.setItem("task",JSON.stringify(task));
                                        this.props.history.push("/taskdetails/");
                                    }}>
                                        <div className="name">{task.name}</div>
                                        <div className="sub">
                                            <div className="type">Dataset: {task.dateSetName}</div>
                                            <div className="members">{task.userList.length + " participants"}</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="del-wrap" onClick={(e)=>{
                                            e.stopPropagation();
                                            e.preventDefault();
                                            this.triggerDelete(task);
                                        }}>
                                            <img src={require("../../images/cancel.svg")}/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                );
                            })
                        }
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

How should I modify my `triggerDelete()` method? So that the particular card gets deleted.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pass `index` of the deleting task to the `triggerDelete` function and then just remove that index from `this.state.taskList` array.

```
<div className="del-wrap" onClick={(e)=>{
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      this.triggerDelete(task, index);
   }}>
        <img src={require("../../images/cancel.svg")}/>
</div>
```

And in `triggerDelete` function

```
triggerDelete(task, index){
   if(window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this task?")){
      let taskList = [...this.state.taskList]
      taskList.splice(index, 1);
      this.setState({taskList: taskList})
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain this line -> ` k.splice(index, 1);`

Comment: @stonerock That line will remove one element at `index` from the array. You can read about this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: splice just takes the index of the element and will remove one element after index i.e. the element you want to delete and everything will be same as before. The thing with splice is it doesn't create new copy of the array. Mutating states is not a good thing always.

Comment: @Prakash How will I get index parameter ? I am displaying data from REST API in card see the response -> https://imgur.com/a/VwWsQJF

Comment: I could not understand index parameter from where will it come ?

Comment: @stonerock  from here => `this.state.taskList.map((task,index)=>{`

Comment: The index represent the imdex of element in the array.

Answer (score 1):

you need to write the logic to delete the task, its easier to do it if you pass the index of the task to triggerDelete. `window.confirm` returns a boolean value indicating whether `OK or Cancel` was selected `(true means OK).`

```
import React, {Component} from "react"; 

export default class Tasks extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            taskList:[],
            taskName:"",
            type:"classification",
            datasetName:"",
            allDatasets:[],
            users:[],
            names:[]
        }
    }

triggerDelete(index){
        if(window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this task?")){

           this.setState(prevState => ({
               taskList: [...prevState.taskList.slice(0, index), ...prevState.taskList.slice(index + 1)]
           }))

        }
    }

render(){
        return(
            <div className="tasks-wrap">
                <h1 onClick={()=>{
                   this.props.history.push("/taskdetails");
                }}>Your Tasks</h1>
                {
                            this.state.taskList.map((task,index)=>{
                                return(
                                    <div key={index} className="item-card" onClick={()=>{
                                        window.sessionStorage.setItem("task",JSON.stringify(task));
                                        this.props.history.push("/taskdetails/");
                                    }}>
                                        <div className="name">{task.name}</div>
                                        <div className="sub">
                                            <div className="type">Dataset: {task.dateSetName}</div>
                                            <div className="members">{task.userList.length + " participants"}</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="del-wrap" onClick={(e)=>{
                                            e.stopPropagation();
                                            e.preventDefault();
                                            this.triggerDelete(index);
                                        }}>
                                            <img src={require("../../images/cancel.svg")}/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                );
                            })
                        }
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your approach but when the dialog box comes and when I click on `ok` entire web page becomes blank after that.

Comment: are you sure you used slice and not splice, also can you confirm what is the state after update in setState callback